# has_many :through and build

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models, Account, User and Contact:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account

  has_many :contacts, :through => :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'

  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I'm trying to scope build a new contact through the user record, like this in my contacts controller.

```
def create
    @contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        ...
      else
        ...
      end
    end
end
```

When I do this, I don't receive any errors, the contact record is saved to the database however the account_id column is not set on the contact, and it is not added to the collection so calling @current_user.contacts returns an empty collection.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `build` makes a new instance of Contact in memory, but you would need to manually set the `account_id` on the record (e.g. `@contact.account_id = current_user.account.id`), or perhaps set it in a hidden field in the `new` form used to display the contact for creation such that it is picked up in the params array passed to the `build` method.

You might also want to consider whether `accepts_nested_attributes_for` may be helpful in this case.  Another option may be to use `delegate`, although in both cases, your use may be sort of the opposite of what these are intended for (typically defined on the "parent").

Update:
In your case, the `build` method is added to both the User instance and to the Account (maybe "Owner") instance, because you have both a many-to-many relationship between User and Contact, as well as a one-to-many relationship between Account and Contact.  So to get the `account_id` I think you would need to call Account's build, like

```
@contact = current_user.accounts.contacts.build(params[:contact])
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tom. So it would seem I've misunderstood how build works - I assumed that calling user.contacts.build gave me an instance (in memory) but one that was already assigned to that user (or account).

I want to avoid using the nested attirbutes where possible as don't want to be padding account and user IDs around in the form.

Comment: Hmm, I think your understanding is correct (I am reading the doc on this for the 423rd time: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), in particular "Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved."  So now that I look more carefully, I think I see the issue.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom - that seems to work very nicely - I can't complain with that at all. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, actually.  That 423rd read of the doc helped me unlearn something I have believed to be true for several years now!